# How to get index in an mutable array?

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I know `indexOfObject` could return the index of the element in an array, but I check this method is an `NSArray` method rather than an `NSMutableArray` method, and the element in my array is object, does that matter? Because currently my program crashes when the following code gets invoked.

```
Class *obj = [[Class alloc] init];
obj.textField1 = outlet1.text;
obj.textField2 = outlet2.text;
NSUInteger index = [myMutableArray indexOfObject:obj];
outlet1.text = [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:index-1] textField1];
outlet2.text = [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:index-1] textField2];
[obj release];
```

What I am trying to do here is when I call above code, those outlets show the details of the previous object in the array. HELP?

Ok, here is what I really want to do:

I want to create an object by entering stuff in two text fields, then store the object in an array. The array I'm talking about is already declared in the header file and allocated space. The above code is actually a method to show the previous object that's already created. The first three lines are intended to make an object that represents the current one showing in the text fields. Then I want to look it up in my array and get the index of it. The reason I use "index-1" is because I want to see the previous object I created. And by "crash" I mean the program simply exits and goes back to the home screen on my simulator.
Thanks!

---

All right, I have finally worked out my solution to my problem, I found another way to get the current object, instead of "creating" an "new" object and compare it with ones in the array, I use a flag to record the index of the current object on the screen and decrement it to get the previous object. Anyway, thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSMutableArray extends NSArray and inherits all of its methods. So calling `objectAtIndex:` on an NSMutableArray is fine.

Without a crash log I can't tell what the problem is, but my first guess would be that `index-1` is `-1` when `index` is `0`, or out of bounds when `indexOfObject:` returns `NSNotFound`.

Comment: By "crash" I mean when I run my program, it just exits. The index couldn't be 0 because the first three lines of code get the index of the last element in my array, and there are some elements that are already existed.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing index - 1 which, if index == 0 then will be an invalid position. The function returns an INDEX. which is already 0 based. :)

Comment: I am trying it on an multi-element array, the first three lines of code get the index of the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Michael, to store the object in a mutable array...

```
YourObject *obj = [[YourObject alloc] init];
obj.textField1 = ... ;
obj.textField2 = ... ;

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
[array addObject:obj];
```

Later, to get the object from the mutable array...

```
for (ID *obj in array) 
{
  if ([obj isKindOfClass:[YourObject class]]) 
  {
    outlet1.text = (SomeObject)obj.textField1;
    outlet2.text = (SomeObject)obj.textField2;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I didn't supply enough of my code...I have already had an array called "myMutableArray", and it has some objects in it. The object has two properties that have to be specified in two text fields. What I want to do is get the index of the current object whose properties are currently shown in the text fields.

Comment: @Michael - I agree with titaniumdecoy and ExtremeCoder, there is no reason to use index-1. Just use index and you'll get the object you want.

Other than that, I'm not really sure what you are trying to do with your code. Sorry mate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when is `obj` even put into the array in your above code? It seems as though you  are trying to see if a `Class` object is in your array, but you are allocating a new one, and then checking. You should use `indexOfObject:` if you have an actual reference to the object in the array, otherwise, how could it be in there? Also, `indexOfObject:` returns `NSNotFound` if the object doesn't exist, which is probably why your method is crashing. If you want to find the earliest object of a certain class in your array, try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [myMutableArray count]; i++){
  if([[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[Class class]]){
    // Do stuff.
    break;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for your debugger.  Put a breakpoint in the line that crashes, and check the values of your variables.  It sounds like you expect the variables to have a certain value (last object in the array), but suppose the array is empty?  GDB is your friend, and is even better in Xcode 4.1